# use asp:LinkButton in umbraco

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

im creating a umbraco plugin, which uses an asp:LinkButton. which looks something like this

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="ObjectInformationBtn" class="link" runat="server" Text="View Full Details of Item" OnClick="ObjectInformationBtn_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

when I test this plugin locally I get the following result

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('DisplayControl$ObjectInformationBtn','')" class="link" id="DisplayControl_ObjectInformationBtn">View Full Details of Item</a>
```

however when I put the plugin on the website I get a complete different results, which looks like this

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

can someone please tell me what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the ascx containing the linkbutton is published to the production website in the usercontrols folder?

Comment: this was in preview mode, is there a difference ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Macro created that references the User Control that contains the LinkButton?